# testing for equal at bit level using logic gates

Tags: binary, logic

I am trying to do gate level analysis for an ALU that can handle A==B, so far i have if a-b=0 then a==b.

In binary (we are using 2 bit) i have for `1-1`, which is `01-01`.

As this is at gate level i need to do `A xor Binverse xor Cin(which is 01 for 2's complement)`.

Which equates to `01 xor 10 xor 01 = 11 xor 01= 10`, but shouldn't I be looking for `01-01=00`?

any tips on how to test for equal at gate level?

Comment: if handling A == B, how does C enter into it?

Comment: @Andras I am testing A == B by using an adder/subtractor, where A and B are inputs, Cin is the carry in term, as A-B is just A+Binverse+1, i set Cin to 1

Comment: ah, thanks.  I may have misunderstood the question then

Comment: by "gate level analysis" do you mean you have to build the ALU out of gates?  you then need a 2-bit adder with carry-in, and carry propagation between the two bits.

Answer (score 0):

binary xor will produce 0 when its two inputs are identical.  a XOR b will be 0 when a == b.  To test for 0, or the bits together, and if the result is 0, the bits were all 0.  A 0 result from the or means equal, non-zero means not equal -- so invert the result.

using an adder/subtractor, `A + Binverse + Cin=1` will produce 0 if a == b (and a carry out) as you say

`A xor Binverse xor Cin` looks like the behavior of the least significant bit; you need the same gates for the most significant bit too, plus carry-in generation from lsb to msb